# Relationship between P(A|X,Y), P(X|Y) and P(A|X)?

Tags: conditional-probability, networks, subset

My statistics training is only basic, so forgive any embarrassing misunderstandings.

Here's my situation:

1. I have a graph (a big one) with 20,770 nodes. This is Y.
2. I have a subgraph, X (subset of Y), with about 70 nodes.
3. I have a random set of 10-30 nodes (called A), some of which may be in X, and some which may be in ~X.

My Progress: I can easily get P(X|Y) and P(A|X).

Question: I'm wondering if I can get P(A|X,Y) from the other two? How does one go about conceptualizing conditional probabilities, once the complexity has "unions" on either sides of the conditionals?

Does this make sense?

Comment: What is $A$? the random set in 3.?

Comment: Yes - my apologies! I so thought I had written that it was. I will edit that now.